# Determining the limit of $x_{n+1} = x_n + 1/(3 x_n^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that 
>   $$
>   x_1 > 0,
>   \qquad
>   x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{3 x_n^2}
> $$
>   Check whether the sequence converges, and if so find its limit.

So I know that a sequence converges if it is bounded and monotone. So I proved those two (hopefully correct):

> Proving that $x_n > 0$ for all $n$:
>
> Base: $x_1 > 0$
>   Hypothesis: $x_n > 0$
>   Step:
>   $$
>            \text{$x_n > 0$ and $\frac{1}{3 x_n^2} > 0$}
>   \implies x_n + \frac{1}{3 x_n^2} > 0
>   \implies x_{n+1} > 0
> $$
>
> Proving that the sequence is monotone increasing:
>   $$
>     x_{n+1} - x_n
>   = x_n + \frac{1}{3 x_n^2} - x_n
>   = \frac{1}{3 x_n^2}
>   > 0
>   \qquad
>   \text{for all $n$}
> $$

Now, I've tried finding the limit, like this:
$$
           \exists \alpha = \lim_{x \to \infty} x_{n+1}
  \implies \alpha = \alpha + \frac{1}{3 \alpha^2}
  \implies \frac{1}{3 \alpha^2} = 0
$$

Where I end up with a conclusion that the limit is equal to infinity, meaning that the sequence diverges. So what am I doing wrong here? Is one of my proofs incorrect or is my limit calculation wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong. The sequence diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: You are correct, the limit is  $+\infty$.

Comment: Shouldn't the sequence converge to a real number (not infinity) if it's bounded and monotone? 
Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Koy if a sequence is bounded above and monotone increasing, then the sequence is convergent. But you've shown that the sequence is bounded below, not bounded above. Hope you'll get it. :)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: In such a situation is it useful to compute some $$x_n$$

Comment: Are you sure it's not $x_{n+1}=\dfrac{x_n+1}{3x_n^2}$?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine, but you may simply notice that $x_{n+1}^3 \geq x_n^3+1$ implies $x_n\geq\sqrt[3]{n-1+x_1^3}$.